# Flutter web - How to select multiple text on mouse drag

Tags: flutter

I'm working with flutter web. I want to select multiple text in multiple line when I press and drag mouse but I can't find solution. I used SelectableText but it only allows to select when press on the text area. Anyone have ideas, help me please. Thanks in advance.

I want to select text like my following picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy texts natively without any package using SelectionArea present in flutter
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectionArea-class.html

**sample code sniopet to get started quickly**

```
return SelectionArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const <Widget>[
                Text('Row 1'),
                Text('Row 2'),
                Text('Row 3'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

or this if you want to select images as well
https://github.com/wilsonowilson/better_selection

**sample code snippet**

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SelectableScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
             ...
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```